# Git remote repo, not showing the files

Tags: git

I've setup a remote git repo and pushed my local repo to the remote repo.  This worked fine as expected, however on the remote repo, I don't see the files associated to the project, it just has `branches`, `config`, `description`, `HEAD`, etc.

Where are the actual project file for the repo?

Here's what I did:

Remote Server:

```
cd /var/www/directory
git --bare init
```

Local Project (in git repo):

```
git remote add remote root@IP:/var/www/directory
git push remote master
```

This worked, it pushed as you would expect.  Just when I go to `/var/www/directory` the project files aren't there, only git related files.

Comment: Could you please provide git commands used to add git remote, merge changes and push commits to remote? Are you merging commits on your local branch with remote one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a "bare" repo.  It doesn't contain the files just information about the commits.

> A "bare" repository in Git just contains the version control information and no working files (no tree) and it doesn't contain the special .git sub-directory. Instead, it contains all the contents of the .git sub-directory directly in the main directory itself.

http://bitflop.com/document/111

It looks like you want to push to deploy your changes.  Rather what you should do is create a non-bare repo in your `/var/www/directory` and pull from your developement repo or a bare repo.  You will have a non-bare repo in your location and when you want to deploy updates you will run `git pull` from the directory which will update the files.  This will also allow you easily move the code to a previous version if there are major issues with the last updates using `git checkout <SHA>`

Comment: Thank you, so if I create a non-bare repo, but when I push to it I get  `[remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)`

Comment: I'm a little confused what you mean by pull from development repo or a bare repo.  So we have say 5 servers that we 'deploy' to.  I'd like to be able to push to all of these remote repos for our deployment.

Comment: You can't push to a non-bare repository.  You will need to have your deployments pull the code from a remote repository.  You will want to have a script log onto the server and do a `git pull` to get the updates.  If you were able to push to a non-bare repo it could cause all sorts of trouble as you would be able to push changes to a developers repo and change what the state of their repo.

Comment: So then I need to set it up as a bare repository, but then where are the files?

Comment: @dave your files are stored internally by git as special blob objects. You can access them using low-level git commands

Comment: @jzelenkov so this remote repository is a server that needs to run the code from the repo, so this wouldn't work?

Comment: @dave no. Not in that form. What you could do is to setup another non-bare git repository, which your server will use to run some tasks on the real code. Essentially you want to separate concerns: one (bare) git repo is used as a git hosting, another (non-bare) one to run some tasks (CI?). You could have both git-hosting-server and action-performing-server on the same machine, just not in the same git repo.

Comment: @jzelenkov so I would push to the bare repo, then have the code in the non-bare? When a push is made to the bare repo, some tasks are run to update the code in the non-bare? Maybe it's easier to just have a task that ssh's to the remote server's and pulls?

Comment: @dave exactly. Use your bare repo as a central one and use git hooks to run actions on events (e.g. post receive).

Answer (score 2):

As @Schleis pointed out, it's a bare repository. Your commits are actually there. You cannot see them, because they are stored as git blob files. You can verify that your commit is present by running `git log`. It should show the same `commit sha` as in your local repo.

```
$ cd server

(BARE:master)$ git log
commit 19b7105fac9e44d0130d662d3d372340b0e9faea
Author: Jevgeni Zelenkov <jevgeni.zelenkov@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Dec 11 16:21:36 2013 +0100

    init

$ cd ../local

(master)$ git log
commit 19b7105fac9e44d0130d662d3d372340b0e9faea
Author: Jevgeni Zelenkov <jevgeni.zelenkov@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Dec 11 16:21:36 2013 +0100

    init
```

---

As of version Git 1.7.0 only `--bare` repositories can accept push & pull commands. So if you want to use your git repository as a server, it must be `--bare`.

---

`git-show` is a universal command to work with git internals. [git show man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html)